# How do i add a git: link reference in vs code help menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i `cmd + shift + p` i get the following screen in vs code

[image: vs code cmd + shift + p]

One of the options i see is `keyboard shortcut references`, When i click on this link , it opens a tab in the browser which showcases all the keyboard shortcuts.

Now i'd like to add a similar link titled `Git: Open Aliases` with a link that goes to **[HERE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GitAlias/gitalias/master/gitalias.txt)**. How do i do this ?

Comment: internally it uses `window.open()`, but they somehow have monkey patched it to show an error message that you should use an `IOpenerService` but that type of object is not available in the public API

Comment: @rioV8 i see thanks , i was hoping there would be a some kind of macro or setting i can add , just like the ability to create a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of the `IOpenerService` is in the API as `vscode.env.openExternal`

You can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) v0.14.1

Use the command `htmlRelatedLinks.openURL` it works the same as the Ctrl-Link-Click. You get the **Trust** dialog.

Define a keybinding

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+g",
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openURL",
    "args": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GitAlias/gitalias/master/gitalias.txt"
  }
```

If you want a command in the Command Palette you have to define it in the `package.json` file of an extension. In this file is the string used to display in the Command Palette.

In this extension I have defined a command to open the GitAlias page and show the command in the Command Palette as: `Git: Open Aliases`

You can set a key binding for this command.